# List all overlapping intervals efficiently

Tags: algorithm, interval-tree

Let T be a given interval tree (of size n) and
i be an interval. Let k be the number of intervals in T that overlap i.
I need to find an algorithm to list all of them in time O(min(n, k log n)).

Comment: There is only one interval `i`? If there is only one interval, a simple O(n) algo should work, what is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you just need to traverse the tree and stop whenever you got `k` overlapping intervals.
Lets mark the range you are currently checking by `t`, then you will need to check `t` against `i` as follows.
The first interval is `t` and the second is your `i`.

```
|------|
  |--|
```

Add `t` and you can stop iterating.

```
  |--|
|------|
```

Add `t` and go both left and right.

```
    |------|
  |---|
```

Add `t` and go only left

```
|------|
     |---|
```

Add `t` and go only right

```
      |------|
|---|
```

Go left (without adding `t`)

```
|------|
         |---|
```

Go right (without adding `t`)